# Capture Data from Website Updates via Webhooks?

Tags: automation, webhooks, zapier, yahoo-api

Programming newbie here who needs help with the following: Most weekdays Yahoo Finance publishes Analyst Reports on https://finance.yahoo.com/research. Every time an Analyst Report is published/updated, I want to capture it in a structured table with the following data points: Date Published/Updated, Stock Symbol, Name of Company, Title of Analyst Report (Article Headline), URL to Analyst Report (Article), Current Price, and Summary. Not every element is exposed on the Yahoo Analyst Report page (since it’s a paid service), but for now I just want to capture the exposed aforementioned info in an automated way.

I tried Zapier Webhooks but am not sure how to setup the automation Zap. Please suggest how to do so or an alternative method.

[image: Yahoo Finance Research Reports main page with latest report]

[image: Latest Yahoo Finance Research Report landing page]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try web scrapping. look into requests and beautifulSoup library of python.
check this article https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/